# eclipse 3.7 indigo on ubuntu 11.04 unable to install plugins

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-11.04, eclipse-indigo

I installed ubuntu 11.04 by wubi on win7. I notice that default eclipse on ubuntu 11.04 is 3.5 galileo(if installed from software center), so I install following some instructions [here] http://colinrrobinson.com/technology/install-eclipse-ubuntu/ . But for some reason when I tried to install any plugins for indigo, it says "unable to read Repository (any plugin websites)..."

I browsed some related stuff on internet and find it's not rare, but most of this case is due to proxy or svn. I'm not using any svn or proxy, and galileo just works fine on same operating system.

Can anybody give me some hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed eclipse indigo in ubuntu 11.04 following this instructions (they ask you to install the galileo version from software center and then to replace it with the indigo version) http://foo-gr.blogspot.com/2011/08/installation-of-latest-eclipse-in.html
it worked just fine; I installed some plugins such as maven, subversion, arena. 
sorry for my english, good luck